# pygame image size in kb (not in pixels)

Tags: python, image, pygame, sizeof

How get from *pygame.image* size (in kb/bytes) in memory? Unfortunately, there is no direct method to check the size of the *surface*.

For the test, i have 2 files (39kb and 1.9mb)

```
aa = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
bb = pygame.image.load(filename2).convert_alpha()
print sys.getsizeof(aa)
print sys.getsizeof(bb)
```

Result:

```
64
64
```

This is (probably) variable size, not stored image.
The only thing I came up with was tostring:

```
print "Size %d" % sys.getsizeof(pygame.image.tostring(aa, "RGBA")) 
print "Size %d" % sys.getsizeof(pygame.image.tostring(bb, "RGBA"))
```

And got:

```
Size 637 
Size 39923749
```

38mb ? Strange and not accurate. How check real memory usage?

BR
Parasit

Answer (score 0):

use os:

```
import os
print os.stat('image.jpg').st_size
```

this will print the size of the image in bytes

if you are trying to get the memory of iit instead of the file size try:

```
aa = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
print aa.nbytes
```

Comment: I need memory usage, but sorry, it not working:

    AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'nbytes

Comment: See also [Surface.get_bytesize](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_bytesize)